# How can I use optional chaining to unwrap swift variables

Tags: ios, swift

**I've received the following compiler error**

> "value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!'or '?'?"

**This is my code**

```all
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text;

    // check for empty fields
    if userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userConfirmPassword.isEmpty
    {
        //Display alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required");
        return;
    }
```

The error shows at line:

```
if userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userConfirmPassword.isEmpty
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not unwrapped the text fields in your code.

The system does not know if there is text present in your textfield. So, when you say:

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
let userConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text;
```

The values in userEmail, userPassword and userConfirmPassword are Optional Strings. To force unwrap them, you can do the following:

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text!;
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text!;
let userConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text!;
```

But, bear in mind that if the user does not enter any value in the textfields, you will get a crash.

Instead of force unwrapping, you should use safe unwrap, like this:

```
if let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text {
    //Do something
} else {
    //Handle case where input is nil
}
```

You can read more about optionals and their unwrapping [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Answer (score 1):

Brush up on Swift basics, check out the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) guide for help with this kind of problem.

But in general...

Any `textField.text` property is an optional, meaning it could be nil.

Therefore your variables like `userEmail` are optional as well, and could be nil.

You can't call a property or method on an optional variable without first unwrapping it.  There's two ways to do this.

`userEmail!.isEmpty` says that you guarantee that userEmail is not nil

`userEmail?.isEmpty` says maybe you're not sure and only check isEmpty is userEmail happens to not be nil

You can also unwrap an optional using if let:

```
if let userEmail = userEmail, userPassword = userPassword, userConfirmPassword = userConfirmPassword where userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userConfirmPassword.isEmpty {
    //do stuff
}
```

That's the best short explanation I can give.  Study, learn, code.